# Javascript - How to disable the print dialog after first show?

Tags: javascript, printing

On one of our pages the user has the option to print a selected list of html pages. This is how it is at the moment

```
var rowcount = FrmMain.RowCount;
var frame = FrmMain.Frame;
for(i=1;i<=rowcount;i++)
{
    var obj = FrmMain.elements("chk_" + i);
    if(obj.checked)
    {
        frame.src = FrmMain.elements("hpath" + i).value;
        window.frames[frame.id].focus();
        window.frames[frame.id].print();
    }
}
```

Now this works fine. The problem is that on each loop the print dialog box is displayed and the user has to click print.

Basically, what I'm asking is whether that is a way to supress this dialog. It must appear at the first time but hide thereafter. Some thing like below

```
var show = true;
...
{
    ...
    {
        ...
        if(show)
        {
            window.frames[frame.id].focus();
            window.frames[frame.id].print();
            show = false;
        }
        else
        {
            window.frames[frame.id].focus();
            window.frames[frame.id].printwithoutdialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I've been clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really think that a webpage can print silently and automatically?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I knew. I'm guessing it can't by your comment.

Comment: is this for an internal site or public website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security / privacy reasons, this is impossible.
Otherwise, ads would automatically print their brochures.

Instead, you can combine all of the pages into a single frame.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have an option bypass the dialog, but it can't be done in javascript.